# DATEDIFF function between different tables and multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, datediff

I had been working on a DB with the main goal to manage a sort of big parking lot, keeping track of all the entry / exit activities.

What i'm trying to do now it is to find out both how long a truck stayed in the parking area before it left and if it's still inside, count the days.

Here is the DDLS

```
Table: inoutgateterra
Columns:
idinoutgateterra int(11) AI PK 
nome varchar(15) 
cognome varchar(15) 
nbadge varchar(10) 
identity_card varchar(15) 
targaveicolo_INGATE varchar(10) 
targatrailerdelivered_INGATE varchar(10) 
targatrailerexpected_OUTGATE varchar(10) 
targatrailer_OUTGATE varchar(10) 
shippingcompany varchar(20) 
DATA_INGATE datetime 
DATA_OUTGATE datetime 
bisarche_DDT varchar(15)


Table: ingatemare
Columns:
idingatemare int(11) AI PK 
targatrailer_IN_NAVE varchar(10) 
description varchar(10) 
DATA_INGATEMARE datetime 
id_veicolo_na_INGATEMARE varchar(20)

Table: outgatemare
Columns:
idoutgatemare int(11) AI PK 
targatrailer_OUTNAVE varchar(10) 
broker varchar(20) 
description varchar(10) 
DATA_OUTGATEMARE date 
id_veicolo_na_OUTGATEMARE varchar(20)
```

And here is the query i run.

```
SELECT 
U . *,
C . *,
DATEDIFF(U.DATA_OUTGATE, C.DATA_OUTGATEMARE) NumDays,
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), C.DATA_OUTGATEMARE) DAYS 
from
(select 
* from 
trailersflow.outgatemare
 WHERE DATA_OUTGATEMARE = outgatemare.DATA_OUTGATEMARE) C
    left outer join trailersflow.inoutgateterra U 
    ON U.targatrailer_OUTGATE = C.targatrailer_OUTNAVE
    AND U.DATA_OUTGATE >= C.DATA_OUTGATEMARE
    ORDER BY idoutgatemare DESC;
```

Now, since we have frequent customers, i have many records with the same license plate (targatrailer) and different dates in both tables, and the query above compares them all giving me several results i don't really need.
I would finally like to execute the datediff function not only when license plates match (IN/OUT) but restrict it to the closest dates i use in the datediff function.
The system should be similar to a parking lot manager with 2 or more entry/exit gates

UPDATE:
ok, i had to figure out how the sqlfiddle thing works (and what it is first of all)..
So here is the link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be3a3e/1

I just put the fields needed for the query: as you can see i get multiple results for the same license plate and i would like to just keep the one related to the closest date needed for the datediff function.
Aug 10 and 15, (5 days parking) not Aug 15 and july 25th (21 days).

I just updated the sqlfiddle link, removing the third entry, not needed for this query.

Comment: Hello, and welcom to SO. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and add that to question.

Comment: you created 3 tables but only 2 have data samples. How is the criteria for data insertion?

Comment: You are right, the third "ingatemare' table will be used to match dates with the 'Inoutgateterra' table, i didn't write the query but it's basically the same thing as the one I posted. I insert the dates through an HTML form and php / mysqli extension.

Comment: i just updated the sqlfiddle link removing the third entry, not needed for this query.

Comment: My advice would be to solve this by storing a foreign key (of the matching idinoutgateterra value) in table outgatemare. You will have a performance nightmare trying to working which record relates to which by timestamps. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78ddb/1

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for ur help, i'm starting to work on it now. I've one more question since i'm not familiar with foreign keys. My table exists already, so i've to add the terraFK field, but i can't set another auto_increment value besides the primary key, and i'm using an html form with php to populate my tables. Is there an easy way to do that without loosing all my inserted records? I would like the terraFK being populated automatically when users insert datas. Thanks again.